# How to SMS string that base on Base64

Tags: windows-phone-7

HI,

anything different between string and string that base on Base64? I can send out string by SMS programmaticallly. But not sure this will apply to string that is base on  Base64. can someone provide guidance what need to be done on the string base on Base64 and send it by SMS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the text message to just contain the base64 string itself? That should work fine - as far as I'm aware, all the characters used within base64 are also available in text messages. If you mean you want to send arbitrary binary data which you happen to have in base64 form at the moment, that could be harder. It wouldn't really be "text" at that point - I dare say there's a way of sending it (possibly MMS etc) but you should be looking at APIs which take byte arrays rather than strings at that point.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I have encrypted a string with AES Encryption and convert it to base64 after ecnryption is done. I try to send out this base64 string by SMS  but It seems the Telco wont allow. Is this the problem?

Comment: @MilkBottle: I'd expect it to be okay so long as it's an appropriate length. How long is the Base64 string?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The string is short like string str64 sxm839WomWYmJXLt10fFag= = . I pass it to Sms.Body = str64 and send. But can not get thru. What I need to do?

Comment: @MilkBottle: Do other messages get through? I can't see why it would have a problem. Maybe there's something in the pipeline which thinks it's spam...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Let me check. I think it could be the "+" is not added to the phone no when I send out by SMS.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yeah. It went thru after adding "+" to the mobile No!! ThankQ. Since I encrypt the string with Keys. So, the recipient who has my app and the key can decrypt the string which I sent, right? BTW, is SMS only allowed ASCII characters? What about Unicode? Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle: Calling this "encryption" is a little bit strong - it's not providing any real protection; there are no secrets involved. But yes, it can be decoded by anyone. I can't remember the exact character set used for SMS, but there should be documentation somewhere.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ThankQ for highlighting the weakness of this AES encryption. Would appreciate if you could recommend which encryption to use that can be sent via SMS securely. Hope this provide some secure level communication and msg cant be decoded so easily.

Comment: @MilkBottle: Hang on a sec - I was calling the Base64 part weak. That's just an encoding really, not encryption. I'd forgotten about the AES part. My bad. AES should be okay for encryption, although if each message is very short, that could represent an attack vector in itself.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry for not being clear on my part to explain this Base64 string from the AES encryption first. I am happy you gave the explanation that it should work interm of the characters base.

Comment: @MilkBottle: No, it was my fault - you'd already said about using AES to start with. I'm juggling too many things in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to send a Base64String via SMS?

EDIT... thanks to Jon :)

At the risk of another downvote by the almighty Jon Skeet ;) I will provide "some" help... @MilkBottle, if you have a byte[] and you convert it (for example with Convert.ToBase64String) you can send the result as a smsbody. I cannot understand, why you want to do this, but that doesn`t matter. Another (bad) example:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] {0x02, 0x04, 0x07}; 
String smsbody = System.Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
```

The result will look like this "AgQG" and this is able to be send programmatically with the SmsComposerTask.

Hope that helps...

Comment: The chances of that working are very slim, IMO. Taking arbitrary binary data, decoding it as if it were a UTF-16 string and then hoping that all those characters can be represented in SMS seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: Can just send out the MyBase64string itself programmatically via SMS?

Comment: Not only could I not downvote the answer again, but I wouldn't anyway for this - that's an entirely reasonable use of Base64. You might want to replace your answer with your comment :)